# Bet HaMikdash and Olam Haba - Rambam

Tags: rambam, beis-hamikdash, olam-haba-world-to-come

If, as the Rambam says, Olam Haba is something that comes after the days of Mashiach and the ressurrection of the dead, and if it is a completely spiritual reality -  as I read in his Treatise on Resurrection, will there still be a Beit Hamikdash on that time? And if not, how are the prophecies that state that the Beit Hamikdash will stand forever (leolam) to be understood?

Comment: Isn't a Bet Hamikdash a part of physical reality? Welcome to Mi Yodeya! I hope you stick around and enjoy.

Comment: I'll second @DoubleAA's welcome. Please consider [registering](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/login) your account, which will [give you access](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) to more of the site's features. Here, you're asking assuming some premises. Are they true (if so, can you support them?), or would you like us to answer based on a hypothetical?